# actionscript - how to always display numbers in XXXX format

Tags: flash, actionscript, numbers, format, digits

I am currently dealing with a flash program that periodically increases and decreases a variable by a set amount within a set time.  To do this i am using TweenLite.  My problem right now is that:

I want the number to always be 6 numbers long.  So, the number 10 would be displayed as 000010.  156 would be 000156, and so on.  My program as current simply displays the 10 or 156.

How do i make it so a specific text box is always to XXXXXX format?

the reason my situation is slightly different than most is because my numbers are incrementing a lot, which means that they change from X to XX to XXX fluidly, so simply sticking 0000 ahead of my digit isnt a valid response to this problem as there will technically be an extra 0 thrown into mix when the digit changes from X to XX, etc.

I currently have the following code in my flash program :

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var score:Number = 0;             // starting value
var targetScore:Number = 0;            // the value that the starting value will change
                                       // to (it increases before *score* increases)

function showScore():void{
    score_mc.score_txt.text = int(score);         //display score in my text box
    }

button_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaseScore);

function increaseScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
    targetScore+=10;                                 //increase targetScore before score
    TweenLite.to(this, 1, {score:targetScore, onUpdate:showScore, ease:Linear.easeNone}); 
                           // increase score to the same value as target score, 
                           // over 1 second. The Linear.ease bit simply makes it 
                           // a constant change from one number to the next.
    }
```

EDIT : this seems to work perfectly (takes into consideration original format of text too :

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var score:Number = 0;
var targetScore:Number = 0;  

function showScore():void{
    score_mc.score_txt.defaultTextFormat = score_mc.score_txt.getTextFormat();
    if (score < 10){
        score_mc.score_txt.text = "00000" + int(score);
    } else if (score < 100) {
            score_mc.score_txt.text = "0000" + int(score);
        } else if (score < 1000) {
            score_mc.score_txt.text = "000" + int(score);
        } else {
            score_mc.score_txt.text = "00" + int(score);
        }

}

button_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaseScore);
function increaseScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
    targetScore+=900;
    TweenLite.to(this, 2, {score:targetScore, onUpdate:showScore, ease:Linear.easeNone});

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
public function printScore( score:int ):String
{
    var str:String = "00000" + score; // add the max leading zeros to your number
    return str.substr( str.length - 6 ); // return only the last 6 chars
}
```

Comment: i put this in literally into the code i have mentioned above, outside other functions of course.  Nothing is happening different from b4, still counting up but no number change aparant.

thank you though, its another thing to try and work with - beats not havign any ideas

Comment: i also tried putting the contents of your function into showScore, it didn't work either

Comment: nothing i am trying with this method is working.  im convinced that i cannot play around with strings because this just keeps piling on errors.

Comment: and if i trace str, it never changes (when program is working and i keep str away from the actual number im changing)

Comment: what are the errors you're getting? you should just be able to use it like `score_mc.score_txt.text = printScore(score);`

Comment: RangeError: Error #1003: The radix argument must be between 2 and 36 the same one i said b4 to other guy, im sure it had something to do with string and ints not mixing. tried playing around with different numbers and it had massivley different results which made no sense in corelation to each other. However, i did create a very simple solution (albeit clunky) to my problem and i really don't forsee me putting any more effort into this, spend atleast 6 hours trying to fix this problem and now that i got a fix : if it ain't broken don't try to fix it. Thanks tho :)

Comment: if you're doing `10.toString([2-36])`, the radix that you're passing (the number between 2 and 36) is what's setting the base. I.e., you pass 2 if you want to print binary, 10 if you want to print decimal, etc. It's probably not what you want to do :) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html#toString()

Comment: The quickest way of changing a `Number` to a `String` is to just add it to an empty `String` - e.g. `var str:String = myNumber + "";`. You can also use `String( myNumber );`

Comment: all my solution is doing is creating a string (let's call it `A`) with the max number of zeros possible - so `10` would be `0000010`, and `1234` would be `000001234`. Then, to get it down to the 6 character length that you want, we just create a substring of the end of the `A` string, so our previous example of `000001234` would be cut down to `001234`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify your code a bit:

```
function showScore(newScore:String):void{
    score_mc.score_txt.text = newScore;         //display score in my text box
}
```

And also tweenlite code:

```
function increaseScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
   targetScore+=10;                                 //increase targetScore before score
   var newScore = targetScore.toString("000000");
   TweenLite.to(this, 1, {score:targetScore, onUpdate:showScore, onUpdateParams:[newScore], ease:Linear.easeNone}); 
}
```

Comment: ok, i got the following error :

RangeError: Error #1003: The radix argument must be between 2 and 36; got 0.
 at Number$/_toString()
 at Number/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::toString()
 at Panel_fla::MainTimeline/increaseScore()

ill try n see if i can figure out what caused it for now.  Frustratingly i figured out how to make the numbers in XX.XXXX format but still cant do this >.<

thanks tho :)

Comment: by the way, I think you can simply add one line to your ShowScore function instead of what I've written. So your function will look like this:`function showScore():void{
    score_mc.score_txt.text = score.toString("0000000");         //display score in my text box
    }`

Comment: ok, it is the 000000, even if i increase it to 2, just causes problems.  i think because im changing the value as an int and calling it as a string here its causing problems.  Does that sound right?  Sorry, ive dealt with flash before but never in such a way as this, flashlite is getting me into new unknown areas :p.

Comment: ok ill test now but im pretty sure i already tried that (been putting the toString everywhere i can :P)

Comment: You can look into this [link](http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/1011401). And maybe do something like that in your code.

Comment: yeh same error as b4, but repeated 10 times :D (scanning your link now)

Comment: i updated top comment to include the "best thing" i could find.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job but others have left answers that may be more practical and computer friendly,

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var score:Number = 0;
var targetScore:Number = 0;

function showScore():void{
    if (score < 10){
        score_mc.score_txt.text = "000" + int(score);
    } else if (score < 100) {
            score_mc.score_txt.text = "00" + int(score);
        } else if (score < 1000) {
            score_mc.score_txt.text = "0" + int(score);
        }

}

button_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaseScore);
function increaseScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
    targetScore+=50;
    TweenLite.to(this, 2, {score:targetScore, onUpdate:showScore, ease:Linear.easeNone});

    }
```